# Отключение фоновой музыки, когда приложение свернуто

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добавил в приложение сервис с фоновой музыкой и возникла следующая ситуация, мелодия продолжала играть, когда приложение свернуто, тогда я решил произвести отключение звука в методе `onPause` и включить его снова в методе `onResume`, но, по понятным причинам, теперь музыка глохнет при переходе в другое активити и снова включается при возврате в `MainActivity`, но необходимо, чтобы мелодия продолжала играть во всех активити, может кто-нибудь подскажет как такое осуществить как можно более простым способом.

P.S.: немного похожий вопрос задавался ранее, но ответа на мой там нет. Вот, что у меня в сервисе:

```
public class MyService extends Service { 
   private static final String TAG = "MyService"; 
   MediaPlayer player; 
   /*@Nullable*/ 
   @Override 
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { 
      return null; 
   } 
   @Override 
   public void onCreate(){ 
      super.onCreate(); 
      player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.morcheeba);
      player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
      player.setLooping(true); //Зацикливаем player.setVolume(100, 100); 
   } 
   @Override 
   public void onDestroy(){ 
      player.stop(); 
   } 
   @Override 
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){ 
      player.start(); 
   }
}
```

Частично вопрос htity (во время входящего звонка музыка приостанавливается, потом сразу продолжается):

```
package com.example.what_the_fuck.bgmusic;  
import android.content.Context;   
import android.content.Intent;    
import android.media.AudioManager;  
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.animation.Animation;  
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener{  
AudioManager audioManager;  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    audioManager = (AudioManager)  
this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);  

    //Запуск фоновой музыки  
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));  
}  

Intent intent = new Intent();  
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  
    switch (v.getId()){  
        case R.id.button:  
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.title_activity_settings), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            intent.setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);  
            startActivity(intent);  
            break;  
        case R.id.button2:  
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.activity1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            intent.setClass(this, Activity1.class);  
            startActivity(intent);  
            break;  
        case R.id.button3:  
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.activity2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            intent.setClass(this, Activity2.class);  
            startActivity(intent);  
            break;  
    }  
}  

//Теперь веселуха!!! Качает музончик!!! ))  
@Override  
protected void onDestroy() {  
    super.onDestroy();  
    audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);  
}  

@Override  
protected void onStart() {  
    super.onStart();  

    /*//Запуск фоновой музыки  
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));*/  
}  

@Override  
protected void onStop(){  
    /*//Останавливаем воспроизведение фоновой музыки (убиваем сервис)  
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));  
    finish();*/  
    super.onStop();  
}  


@Override  
protected void onResume() {  
    super.onResume();  
    /*//Включаем звук фоновой музыки  
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);*/  
}  

@Override  
protected void onPause(){  
    super.onPause();  
    /*//Выключаем звук фоновой музыки  
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);*/  
}  

@Override  
public void onBackPressed(){  
    //Останавливаем воспроизведение фоновой музыки (убиваем сервис)  
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));  
    finish();  
}  

@Override  
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {  
    if(focusChange<=0) {  
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));  
    } else {  
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));  
    }  
}  
/*@Override  
public void onHomePressed(){  
    //Выключаем звук фоновой музыки  
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);  
}*/  
}
```

Comment: Поручить проигрывание музыки сервису.

Comment: Как правильно заметил Sergey, вынесите запуск и остановку мелодии в сервис. Для этих целей отлично подойдёт IntentSerivce

Comment: @Denis, что посоветуете дописать, чтобы необходимые мне условия выполнялись? (код сервиса ниже)

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, вот что у меня в сервисе: `public class MyService extends Service { private static final String TAG = "MyService"; MediaPlayer player; /*@Nullable*/ @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; } @Override public void onCreate(){ super.onCreate(); player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.morcheeba); player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); player.setLooping(true); //Зацикливаем player.setVolume(100, 100); } @Override public void onDestroy(){ player.stop(); } @Override public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){ player.start(); }}`

Comment: @ЕвгенийМ. разместите Ваш код в вопросе. В таком виде трудно что-то разобрать

Comment: @Denis, вроде все правильно добавляю, но в итоге,  все в кучу собирается(

Comment: я сейчас тоже занимаюсь написанием плеера. можете посмотреть мой репозиторий - https://github.com/qbikkx/music-player код в ужасном состоянии, но сервис играет) и еще вот гайд, в котором все неплохо расписано https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/

Comment: @Sviat Volkov я не плейер пишу, но спасибо! обязательно посмотрю все по ссылкам позже!